# NicEdit problem in next line

Tags: nicedit

In one of my website i am using the NicEdit javascript editor. In my editor i couldn't go the next line by pressing enter key. I can type only in single line..is this problem with textarea or NicEdit. I am converting all the textarea to replace with NicEdit.

Answer (score 2):

Saravanan,

I just ran into the exact same problem with nicEdit.

Not sure *why*, but the problem seems to happen only when the editor is added to a text area within a list.

If I put the textarea in a list like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <textarea />
  </li>
<ul>
```

Then the enter key stops working.

If I change the markup to some div tags for instance then the enter key starts working ok.

Note: I tried explicitly specifying a display:block style on the list - thought that might be the problem - but that didn't resolve anything. Add to get rid of the ul/li tags and use divs..

hope this helps

**EDIT:**
This [botsko article](http://www.botsko.net/blog/2009/04/20/wysiwyg-choices-nicedit-vs-tinymce/) mentions the same problem, and there's an [unresolved bug filed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=460740) for it

Answer (score 1):

For the best practice, nicEdit must be put inside a div directly, Don't know the reason, but it seams to be, and without this div wrapper, it didn't work for ie at the first place...

Try to put it inside a DIV wrapper, and i Hope this works